# Use Flow3 on webhosting w/o shell

Tags: web-hosting, typo3-flow

i used extbase/fluid to build a typo3 extension and i liked it. 
I'm planning a web-project and would like to use Flow3 as framework.

Is ist possible to use Flow3 on a hosting solution w/o shell access?
Maybe develop local and put everything on the server once developing is finished
or is shell access a must?

Answer (score 0):

You  could use a php shell.

The shell is not really a must, but Flow3 is developped for having a shell available. So you might run into trouble.